# How to generate random even number in kotlin - Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, math

I am new to kotlin and I'm building an kids maths learning app in which i want to generate random even number in the range of 2 to 50.

I can do this in java like this

```
random = startOfRange+rand.nextInt((endOfRange-startOfRange)/2) *2;
```

but can't convert it to kotlin.

Comment: I have google it before but found no answer anywhere

Comment: if you know in java , AS can convert it into Kotlin for you , or you could just access the java file where you are generating the even number from kotlin code , remember kotlin and java 100 interoperable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Kotlin 1.3:

```
val random = ((startOfRange..(endOfRange)/2).random() * 2)
```

The logic is always the same, divide your end range by 2 then take a random number between that and your start range, then multiply by 2.